# NCache cannot add new local caches / existing local caches through NCache Explorer

Tags: caching, visual-studio-2013, ncache

When I tried to add new local caches through NCache Explore in Visual Studio Pro 2013 / 2015, after I input IP address and cache name , the NCache Explore prompt a error message as below :

```
Error: Alachisoft.NCache.Runtime.Exceptions.ManagementException 
at Alachisoft.NCache.Management.RPC.RemoteCacheServer.ExecuteCommandOnCacehServer(ManagementCommand command)
at Alachisoft.NCache.Management.RPC.RemoteCacheServer.IsCacheRegistered(String cacheId)
at Alachisoft.IntegCommonMVC.Controllers.CommonControl.CommonController.CheckCacheAvailability(String serverNode, String cacheId, Int32 serverPort)
```

Does anyone know how to add the local cache in NCache Explore correctly ?

Comment: Are you using OpenSource version of NCache ?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Open source version of NCache/

Comment: I don't think NCACHE Explorer is supported with the open source version. Use the commands from the installationfolder/bin/tools to manage your caches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCache Explore in Visual Studio Pro 2013 / 2015 is not supported Officially in the open source version.

You can manage it from console with the following steps.

1. Open CMD
2. cd to installation folder; mine is `C:\Program Files\NCache\
3. cd to bin\tools`
4. First check if service is up and running by executing `listcaches.exe`
5. If all is fine then simply do `startcache.exe mycache`
6. If not then check if your IP is correct or not in

   - `config/client.ncconf`
   - `config/config.ncconf`
   - `bin/service/Alachisoft.NCache.Service.exe.config`

Comment: Thanks you very much. Could I using command line to control another machine's cache stop/ start ?

Comment: Yes you can: `startcache.exe mycache /s 20.200.20.96` . For more information do `startcache.exe /? `

Comment: Thanks you very much ! =]

Comment: When I try to execute iistcaches , I get an error which says MachineName value is invalid. Any ideas what is this about ?

Comment: Try giving your IP `listcache.exe /s 192.168.1.100`

Comment: @TheMitraBoy Your machine name might be bounded to some other IP. If you do not provide an IP NCache picks the first one and tries to work with it.

Comment: @BasitAnwer Thanks a lot. I ended up doing it from NCache manager

Comment: Great! Good to know :)